# Network communication isn´t working

Tags: java, networking

I made a little game. Now i want to get the highscore from my Server. The code on the client:

```
        private int getOnlineHighscore() {
    int highscore = 0;
    try {
        socket = new Socket("localhost", 444);
        input = socket.getInputStream();
        System.out.println(input);
        highscore = input.read();
        input.close();
        socket.close();
        input = null;
        socket = null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Verbindung fehlgeschlagen!");
    }
    System.out.println(highscore);
    return highscore;
}
```

And on the Server:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

 public class ReadServer extends Thread {
 private Socket socket;

public ReadServer(Socket socket) {
    super();
    this.socket = socket;
}

public void run() {
    try {
        System.out.println(socket.getInetAddress());
        String result = "";
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/AppData/Roaming/GameServer/.sg"))) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = br.readLine();
            System.out.println("2");
            while (line != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
                line = br.readLine();
            }
            System.out.println("3");
            result = sb.toString();
            System.out.println("3.5");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("4");
        socket.getOutputStream().write(Integer.parseInt(result));
        System.out.println(result);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    try {
        socket.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

public static void main(String[] Args) {
    Socket socket = null;
    ServerSocket server = null;
    try {
        server = new ServerSocket(444);
        while (true) {
            socket = server.accept();
            new ReadServer(socket).start();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    try {
        server.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
}
```

If I run it, the client function returns:
    -1
The server writes in the console(not important I think):
    /127.0.0.1
    2
    3
    3.5
    4

How to solve the problem? I want to send an int stored on my Server to a client.

-Jakob

Comment: -1 occurs if you have reached end of the stream. Do a br.reset() after sending the result . It will reset the stream and you should be fine

Comment: Isn´t working, same problem.

Comment: My bad. Didn't read the whole problem.  To send primitive data types , you should use DataOutputStream

Answer (score 1):

`-1` is returned by `read()` to specify end of stream , make sure  data to be read is being returned .

Answer (score 0):

What is the highscore stored in the file? I believe the file is empty and it fails on parsing the integer but as your catch block is empty, you don't see the exception. Put printStacktrace or rethrow.

Another problem is that OutputStream sends only bytes and therefore `write` method sends only low 8 bits. To send int wrap the stream with [`DataOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html) and `DataInputStream` on the client side.

Comment: The file content is "104" in only one line. Shouldn´t give at least something back? If I add System.out.println(result); to my Server, it writes "104" in the console.

Comment: Does it end with new line? Try calling trim () before passing to parseInt. Also print the exception, this will definitely give a clue.

Comment: Thank you, the trim() made the difference!